# I want async parallel not to break on error

Tags: asynchronous, callback, parallel-processing

I'm using [caolan/async](https://github.com/caolan/async) specifically `.parallel()` and I'm assembling an object of strings. When there's an error the whole thing exists and doesn't finish, even the processes without errors.

```
async.parallel({
  "color": color,
  "brand": brand,
  "sku": sku,
}, function(err, result) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(result);
});
```

If `brand` returns an error, I don't get any information. I'd rather `brand:false`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async.parallelPlus = function(functions, callback) {
  var wrap = function(func) {
    return function(callback) {
      func(function(err, value) {
        if (err) return callback(null, false);
        return callback(null, value);
      });
    }
  }
  var newFunctions = {};
  for (var func in functions) {
    newFunctions[func] = wrap(functions[func]);
  }
  return async.parallel(newFunctions, callback);
}
```